# How do I run my YOLOv3 algorithm with OpenCV in Visual Studio 2022 using GPU?

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, object-detection, yolo

I am new to computer vision and object detection and I have came across this exercise on performing object detection on videos with OpenCV, pre-trained YOLOv3 model and the coco dataset. I am currently using visual studio 2022 with the lastest opencv-python and the needed files such as the weight, cfg and name files. The algorithm works, however, the processing speed when displaying the output video has a low fps. I searched online and most of them suggested of using a GPU.

In my current setup, I have a **CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 @3.20GHz** and **GPU: NVDIA GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST**

I am planning on making a custom dataset for training later on. Is there anyway I can perform my object detection and training using the GPU on visual studio 2022? If so, what procedures and steps do I need to do in order to do so? Thanks in advance.

python code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load YOLO
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("YOLO_COCO/yolov3.weights", "YOLO_COCO/yolov3.cfg")
classes = []
with open("YOLO_COCO/coco.names","r") as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

# Load Video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/overpass.mp4')

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()

    height, width, channel = img.shape

    # Detecting Objects
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416,416), (0, 0, 0), swapRB=True, crop=False) 

    net.setInput(blob)
    outs = net.forward(output_layers)


    # Show information on the screen
    # Initialise variables
    class_ids = []
    confidences = [] 
    boxes = []

    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence>0.5:
                # Object detected
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)

                # Rectangle coordinates
                x = int (center_x - w/2)
                y = int (center_y - h/2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    # Non Maximum Suppresion (Keep one box)
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5, 0.4)

    # Label object
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    for i in range (len(boxes)):
        if i in indexes:
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i],2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(img, label + "  " + confidence, (x, y+20), font, 1, color, 2)

    cv2.imshow("Video", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1

Make sure your OpenCV already bind with CUDA. If you don't have it, you can check [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/build-opencv-from-source-with-cuda-for-gpu-access-on-windows-5cd0ce2b9b37) because you're using Visual Studio but thats for Windows.

If you are using linux, you can check [here](https://towardsdev.com/installing-opencv-4-with-cuda-in-ubuntu-20-04-fde6d6a0a367)

Step 2

put this code before start the loop

```
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
```

Tadaa, you're done!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the instruction. I have been following the steps for windows and when I configure my files on CMake (Step 10.5 in the tutorial), my python3_numpy_include_dirs is empty and my openCV modules to be built does not contain python3. What do you think is the problem in my case and how should I fix the issue?

Comment: it's a reference for CMake to bind Cuda with your existing python interpreter. Have you refer it to the path of your installed numpy library manually? something like `C:\Program Files\python\lib\.....`

Comment: I fixed the problem by reinstalling everything, I think I made some mistakes along the way. I have configured and generated the "build" file according to the tutorial without a problem (up to step11). However when I try to build the "all build" file under "CMakesTarget", it gives me 200+ errors. Mainly on linker tools error (LNK1181) and MSBuild errors (MSB8066). I have tried to delete and reconfigure the build folder but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: I never use CUDA in windows. I have tried to do it but it's more complicated because windows is not open source (I think?) not like Linux. I've done many times installing and building CUDA in Linux because I think it's a lot easier (even it's still complicated)